# Как создать эффект для radio

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

На днях столкнулся с подобным эффектом, но не разобрался как лучше сделать, а именно сам эффект появления/исчезновения. В ступор ставит "взрыв" окружности и разъединение на более меньшие части.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для достижения такого эффекта используется **SVG** **jQuery** и **GSAP**.

Можно было обойтись и без них, но это жутко увеличило бы объем кода.

```js
let check = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});
let uncheck = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});

check
  .set('.ring', {
    opacity: 1
  })
  .set('.drops', {
    opacity: 0
  })
  .set('.ring0', {
    opacity: 0
  })
  .set('.drop', {
    opacity: 0,
    y: -32,
    scale: .4,
    x: 0,
    transformOrigin: "50%, 0%"
  })
  .set('.ring', {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%"
  })
  .set('.dropTop', {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: .2,
    transformOrigin: "50%, 0%"
  })
  .add('sync')
  .to('.ring', .17, {
    scaleY: .95
  }, 'sync')
  .to('.dropTop', .1, {
    scale: 1,
    y: .5,
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  }, 'sync')
  .to('.dropTop', .1, {
    scale: .3,
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  }, 'sync +=.08')
  .to('.dropTop', .08, {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 40%",
    scale: 0,
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  }, 'sync +=.181')
  .set('.drop', {
    opacity: 1,
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  }, 'sync')
  .to('.drop', .17, {
    y: 0,
    ease: Power1.easeIn
  }, 'sync')
  .to('.drop', .08, {
    scale: .9,
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  }, 'sync +=.02')
  .to('.ring', 2, {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%",
    scaleY: 1,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(.8, .1)
  }, 'sync +=.14')
  .to('.drop', 1.8, {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 10%",
    scale: 1,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(.8, .14)
  }, 'sync +=.14')


uncheck
  .set('.ring0', {
    opacity: 1
  })
  .set('.drop', {
    opacity: 0
  })
  .set('.ring', {
    opacity: 0
  })
  .set('.drops', {
    opacity: 1
  })
  .set('.drop0', {
    rotation: '40deg',
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%"
  })
  .set('.drop1', {
    rotation: '112deg',
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%"
  })
  .set('.drop2', {
    rotation: '175deg',
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%"
  })
  .set('.drop3', {
    rotation: '-110deg',
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%"
  })
  .set('.drop4', {
    rotation: '-35deg',
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%"
  })
  .add('uncheck')
  .to('.drops', .2, {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%",
    scaleX: .5,
    scaleY: .3,
  })
  .staggerTo('.drops', .2, {
    cycle: {
      x: [45, 59, 14, -62, -35],
      y: [-46, 29, 62, 15, -55],
    }
  }, '0.0184', 'uncheck+=.1')
  .to('.ring0', .2, {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%",
    scale: 1.05
  }, 'uncheck+=.1')
  .add('last')
  .to('.ring0', 2, {
    transformOrigin: "50%, 50%",
    scale: 1,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(.8, .1)
  }, 'last')
  .to('.drops', .2, {
    scaleY: .1,
    scaleX: .3
  }, 'last+=0');


check.timeScale(1.27);
uncheck.timeScale(1.14);

$('.toggler').click(function() {
  if (!$('#boom').is(':checked')) {
    check.play(0);
    $('#boom').prop('checked', true);

  } else {
    uncheck.play(0);
    $('#boom').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff, #f0f0f0);
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.bottom a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: .27s;
}

.bottom a:hover {
  color: #C25068;
}

svg {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
}

svg .gooey {
  filter: url("#goo");
}

svg .drop,
svg .dropTop,
svg .drops {
  opacity: 0;
}

svg .toggler {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#boom {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
  left: -1000px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#boom+div:before {
  content: "unchecked";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#boom:checked+div:before {
  content: 'checked';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 600" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <filter id="goo">
   <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur"/>
   <feColorMatrix in="blur" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo"/>
   <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo"/>
  </filter>
  <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
   <stop stop-color="#C25068" offset="0%"/>
   < stop-color="#9E3B5C" offset="100%"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <rect id="Rectangle" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="600"></rect>
 <g class="gooey" transform="translate(330.000000, 230.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <circle class="dropTop" r="10" cx="70" cy="12"/>
  <circle class="drop" r="40" cx="70" cy="70"/>
  <circle class="drops drop0" r="40" cx="70" cy="70"/>
  <circle class="drops drop1" r="40" cx="70" cy="70"/>
  <circle class="drops drop2" r="40" cx="70" cy="70"/>
  <circle class="drops drop3" r="40" cx="70" cy="70"/>
  <circle class="drops drop4" r="40" cx="70" cy="70"/>
  <path class="ring0" d="M70,140 C31.3400675,140 0,108.659932 0,70 C0,31.3400675 31.3400675,0 70,0 C108.659932,0 140,31.3400675 140,70 C140,108.659932 108.659932,140 70,140 Z M70,129.552239 C102.889793,129.552239 129.552239,102.889793 129.552239,70 C129.552239,37.1102067 102.889793,10.4477612 70,10.4477612 C37.1102067,10.4477612 10.4477612,37.1102067 10.4477612,70 C10.4477612,102.889793 37.1102067,129.552239 70,129.552239 Z" id="Combined-Shape"/>
  <path class="ring" d="M70,140 C31.3400675,140 0,108.659932 0,70 C0,31.3400675 31.3400675,0 70,0 C108.659932,0 140,31.3400675 140,70 C140,108.659932 108.659932,140 70,140 Z M70,129.552239 C102.889793,129.552239 129.552239,102.889793 129.552239,70 C129.552239,37.1102067 102.889793,10.4477612 70,10.4477612 C37.1102067,10.4477612 10.4477612,37.1102067 10.4477612,70 C10.4477612,102.889793 37.1102067,129.552239 70,129.552239 Z" id="Combined-Shape"/>
  <circle class="toggler" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0)" r="120" cx="70" cy="70"/>
 </g>
</svg>
<form>
 <input tabindex="-1" id="boom" name="boom" type="checkbox">
 <div></div>
</form>
```

*Раньше ты отвечал на мои вопросы.Но это было раньше :)*

Comment: я не удивлюсь, если ты достал этот эффект на Codepen, но в любом случае спасибо)

Comment: @Arthur обращайся :) ..Если этот эффект был там почему сам не достал ?))

Comment: Дедлайны горят

Comment: @Arthur :DDDDDD